# How to implement Java template as an interface parameter using JPype jproxy in Python

Tags: java, python, pypi, jpype, pyjnius

I want to implement Java Template in Python using JPype.
Template is part of a interface which i am implementing it through JProxy but it does not work if parameter is java template of Generics.

Java Code:

```
public interface GetResultCallback<T> {

    void onSuccess(T result);

    void onFailure(TestError error);

}
```

Python Jpype code:

```
class Get_Callback:

    def onSuccess(self, result) :
        print("I am in success")
        print (result)
        Get_Callback.setResult(result)

    def onFailure(self, err) :
        print("Error")
        print (err)
```

While running this i get error thatOnSuccess method is not implemented as it expects method with template.
Any idea how to implement this using JProxy of Jpype?

Comment: Why do you need the generic parameter in the first place? If you implement it in python then you don't have type information

Comment: Generic parameter is because this interface will implement all type of get method else i have to write separate for each data type, Additionally this is Java part is developer code where i don't have say and what i am building in QA is in Python as per business requirement.